# example to explain unix domain socket - AF_INET vs AF_UNIX

Tags: sockets, unix, network-protocols

while I was reading for what `AF_INET` means, I learned that there is another family called `UNIX domain socket`. Here is the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) I read about this.

I do not understand what this means:

> Unix domain sockets use the file system as their address name space.
>   They are referenced by processes as inodes in the file system. This
>   allows two processes to open the same socket in order to communicate.
>   However, communication occurs entirely within the operating system
>   kernel.

If I want to do `SSH or FTP`, what family do I use `AF_INET or AF_UNIX`. I am actually confused here a bit.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to communicate with a remote host, then you will probably need an `INET` socket.

The difference is that an `INET` socket is bound to an IP address-port tuple, while a `UNIX` socket is "bound" to a special file on your filesystem. Generally, only processes running on the same machine can communicate through the latter.

So, why would one use a `UNIX` socket? Exactly for the reason above: communication between processes on the same host, being a lightweight alternative to an `INET` socket via loopback.

In fact, `INET` sockets sit at the top of a full TCP/IP stack, with traffic congestion algorithms, backoffs and the like to handle. A `UNIX` socket doesn't have to deal with any of those problems, since everything is designed to be local to the machine, so its code is much simpler and the communication is faster. Granted, you will probably notice the difference only under heavy load, e.g. when reverse proxying an application server (Node.js, Tornado...) behind Nginx etc.

Comment: this could be a stupid one: can you give an example where  communication between process on the same host happens?

Comment: It is very common in programming to have processes exchange data with each other, especially multiple instances of the same app, or a group of related apps working together. Using a socket for that exchange is just one of many different mechanisms available for inter-process communication.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple example because architectures involving inter-process communications are often not trivial. The only one that comes to my mind is Chrome Web Browser: you might know that it manages sandboxing by running each tab as a different process plus some other control/render processes. Still, you can use Chrome as a single application because the processes communicates with each other. On Linux, that communication happens through `UNIX` sockets.

Comment: Another example is wpa_supplicant when run as a daemon. The daemon needs high privileges for communicating with the network interface, but giving all those priviliges to each user is very risky. So users control it via a "remote control", which is nothing but a local socket which you can use to send commands to the daemon.

Comment: @eagertoLearn - I'm glad you are interested to know the difference instead of blindly writing codes. A perfect example of application codes that uses `domain socket` is `X server components`. If you are using `GNOME` or `KDE` on your linux, you will see that there will be sockets in `/tmp`. `ls -la /tmp` will reveal the sockets or you can even `find /tmp -type s`. Remy's explanation is the reason `X server components` use `domain sockets`.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - +1 for a well explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

AF_UNIX Sockets provide for great inter-process communication.  Open a socket pair socketpair(..)" and bind to a temporary filename.  Write to one of the pair arrives at the other.  The kernel routes messages without protocol or filesystem overhead.  One can use blocking i/o or select(...) to synchronize threads and processes in a FIFO manner.  I like non-blocking with select and datagram (can get a length) mode but you can choose your own.  Be sure to delete the temporary file on exit (it will have zero bytes but will still show up in the filesystem directory)